# "Help me with my SQL query" questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

Are these types of questions allowed on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL is an accepted topic, so I imagine that a good scenario is to isolate the actual problem you're trying to address, and frame the question around that instead of just "make this work". This should make it acceptable. Make sure to include your current SQL query as a code block and explain what you've tried and what is failing.

By focusing on the problem that is trying to be solved, you help other users that have the same concern to find the solution, even if they don't have the same query structure that you specifically wrote. And, even as you think about the rephrasing, you may even find an existing question that solves the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like the title, but so long as their is a technical/code/syntax type of question involved, yep...

If the title is really what the question is, it'll be downvoted and closed.  In general, the `give me da codez` questions aren't very popular amongst the users.

Comment: Agreed. Effort needs to be put into questions - it helps everyone all around. As an asker, you'll get your answer faster with less need to elaborate on everything. As an answerer, you'll have to be bothered by less need for clarification. As a spectator, you will more easily find the same questions. When it's just "help me with this code", you lose all of these.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is:

Has the user asked something like: "I have three tables in a database that look like `this`. I'm trying to do XYZ, but when I run `this query code`, the results come out like `this`. How can I find the data I'm looking for, in the structure I need?"

Or was it something like: "`Here is my 300-line SQL query,` it won't work, plz gimme teh codez."

So I guess what I'm saying is, the rules for SQL are pretty much the same as any other language.